# Caching data using collection

Tags: java, algorithm

So, I have an issue caching data inside a java collection. When I initialize the app for the first time I use the below function like this,

```
cacheImageAndSounds(0,6);
```

Now once I reach the 4th position from the start I want to remove the previous 3 elements from the collection and cache the next 3 i.e.

```
cacheImageAndSounds(4,10);
```

But as I have 4th, 5th and 6th image already in the cache I won't want to re-bring them inside the cache as they already are present, hence I would only look to download or fetch 7th to 10th image and sound files.

How can I go about doing this, Or how may I tweak my algorithm of caching data inside the map?

This is the function that I use to create cache of images and sound files inside a collection and use it further to retrieve data from it, based on various index values. I use it in a way so that knowingly I can set two indexes and get the required data filled inside the collection.

```
public int cacheImageAndSounds(int startIndex,int lastIndex)
    {
        for(int i=startIndex;i<lastIndex;i++)
        {   
        aq.ajax(data1.get(i), Bitmap.class, new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
                imageFilexxS.put(url, object);
                System.out.println("size of imagefile"+imageFilexxS.size());
            }
        }); 

        aq.ajax(data1.get(i).replace(".png", ".mp3"), File.class, new AjaxCallback<File>() {
            @Override
            public void callback(String url, File object, AjaxStatus status) {
                imageFilexxSm.put(url, object);

                System.out.println("size of songfile"+imageFilexxSm.size());

                if(imageFilexxSm.size()>=6)
                {
                      update(); //call to the UI
                }
            }
        });
       }
      return 1;
    }
```

**Clear the cache and build new one.**

```
public void clearCacheLogic()
    {
        imageFilexxS.clear();
        imageFilexxSm.clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are **not caching** the **index** and checking it, before making the ajax call. Have a new `Set<Integer>` called `processed`. And the method like,

```
public int cacheImageAndSounds(int startIndex,int lastIndex)
    {
        for(final int i=startIndex;i<lastIndex;i++)
        {   
            //check if the index is already processed, if not then make the call
            if(!processed.contains(i)) {
                aq.ajax(data1.get(i), Bitmap.class, new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
                        imageFilexxS.put(url, object);
                        System.out.println("size of imagefile"+imageFilexxS.size());
                        processed.add(i); //once the result comes, mark the index as processed
                    }
                }); 

                aq.ajax(data1.get(i).replace(".png", ".mp3"), File.class, new AjaxCallback<File>() {
                    @Override
                    public void callback(String url, File object, AjaxStatus status) {
                        imageFilexxSm.put(url, object);
                        processed.add(i); //once the result comes, mark the index as processed
                        System.out.println("size of songfile"+imageFilexxSm.size());

                        if(imageFilexxSm.size()>=6)
                        {
                            update(); //call to the UI
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
      return 1;
    }
```

In this way, when you call `cacheImageAndSounds(4,10);`, for the 4th, 5th and 6th index, **no ajax call** will be made since these indices are already present in `processed` Set

Comment: But I have to remove the elements from the processed `Set` once I reach a particular index and I would want to cache the next ones. For example as I have already mentioned in my question -> I am at 4th image and I want to remove the previous images from the `Map`, so that the map would maintain the memory inside it . Hence I would need to clear the `Set` again I mean the first 3 and then lets say I am going back to first then I would obviosly clear the last three and then the `Set` would get the new positions. This should be clear..